# Морской бой. Как правильно расставить корабли?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Пробую написать простенький морской бой на Java. Все почти сделал, кроме правильного алгоритма помещения кораблей на карту. В коде комментариями описано где именно проблема.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Field field = new Field();
    Player player = new Player();
    player.getName();
    field.init();
    final int NUMBEROFSHIPS =10;
    Ship [] ships = new Ship[NUMBEROFSHIPS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFSHIPS; i++) {
        boolean isShipSettedUp = false;
        do { //вот здесь проблемы
             //корабли расставляются рандомно на свободное место на карте
            // получается так, что для последних кораблей не хватает 
           //места и идет зацикливание 
           //Ship(координата Х, координата У,  размер, вертикален ли)
            if (i <=3) ships[i] = new Ship(rand.nextInt(10), rand.nextInt(10), 1, false);
            if (i >3 && i <=6) ships[i] = new Ship(rand.nextInt(10), rand.nextInt(10), 2, false);
            if (i >6 && i <= 8) ships[i] = new Ship(rand.nextInt(10), rand.nextInt(10), 3, false);

            if (i > 8 && i <=9) ships[i] = new Ship(rand.nextInt(10), rand.nextInt(10), 4, false);
            if (field.isCanSetShip(ships[i])) {
                field.setShip(ships[i]);
                isShipSettedUp =true;
           }
        } while(!isShipSettedUp);
    }
    System.out.println("Game start!");
    do {
        field.show();
        System.out.println("Where to shoot?");
        System.out.println("Enter column: ");
        int shootX = player.getShoot();
        System.out.println("Enter row: ");
        int shootY = player.getShoot();
        Shoot shoot = new Shoot(shootX,shootY);
        field.doShoot(shoot);
    } while (field.isNotGameOver());
}
}
```

Класс Field:

```
public class Field {
final int FIELDSIZE = 10;
char[][] cells = new char[FIELDSIZE][FIELDSIZE];
Ship ship;
void init() {
    for (int i = 0; i < FIELDSIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FIELDSIZE; j++) {
            cells[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
}
void setShip(Ship ship) { //помечаю ячейку в массиве, что здесь корабль
    this.ship = ship;
    if (ship.isVertical) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ship.size; i++) {
            cells[ship.positionX + i][ship.positionY] = 'X';
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < ship.size; i++) {
            cells[ship.positionX][ship.positionY + i] = 'X';
        }
    }
}

void doShoot(Shoot shoot) {
    switch (cells[shoot.xCoord][shoot.yCoord]) {
        case '.':
            System.out.println("MISS");
            cells[shoot.xCoord][shoot.yCoord] = '*';
            break;
        case 'X':
            System.out.println("GOAL");
            cells[shoot.xCoord][shoot.yCoord] = '_';
            show();
            break;
        case '*':
            System.out.println("You already shoot here...");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error!");
    }
}

void show() {
    for (int i = 0; i < FIELDSIZE; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            for (int k = 0; k < FIELDSIZE; k++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + k);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < FIELDSIZE; j++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + cells[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

boolean isShipPresent(int positionX, int positionY) {
    return cells[positionX][positionY] == 'X';
}

boolean isNotGameOver() {
    boolean isPresent = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < FIELDSIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FIELDSIZE; j++) {
            if (cells[i][j] == 'X') isPresent = true;
        }
    }
    return isPresent;
}
//Проверка на то, можно ли в данном участке поставить корабль
//Написано не очень правильно, только учусь :(
boolean isCanSetShip(Ship ship) {
    boolean canSet = true;
    if (ship.positionX + ship.size > FIELDSIZE - 1 || ship.positionY + ship.size > FIELDSIZE - 1)
        canSet = false;
    else {

        //Если корабль стоит горизонтально
        if (!ship.isVertical) {
            if (ship.positionX == 0 && ship.positionY > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= ship.size; i++) {
                    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                        if (ship.positionY + j < FIELDSIZE && ship.positionY + j >= 0) {
                            if (isShipPresent(ship.positionX + i, ship.positionY + i)) canSet = false;
                        } else canSet = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (ship.positionY == 0 && ship.positionX > 0) {
                for (int i = -1; i <= ship.size; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
                        if (ship.positionX + i < FIELDSIZE && ship.positionX + i >= 0) {
                            if (isShipPresent(ship.positionX + i, ship.positionY + j)) canSet = false;
                        } else canSet = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (ship.positionX == 0 && ship.positionY == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= ship.size; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
                        if (isShipPresent(ship.positionX + j, ship.positionY + i)) canSet = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (ship.positionX > 0 && ship.positionY > 0) {
                for (int i = -1; i <= ship.size; i++) {
                    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                        if (ship.positionX + j >= 0 && ship.positionY + i >= 0 && ship.positionX + j < FIELDSIZE && ship.positionY + i < FIELDSIZE) {
                            if (isShipPresent(ship.positionX + j, ship.positionY + i)) canSet = false;
                        } else canSet = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            //если корабль вертикально
            //пока не использую. На данный момент все корабли с горизонтальным положением
        }
    }
    return canSet;
}
}
```

Как правильно организовать алгоритм?

Comment: А не пробовали ставить сначала крупные корабли а потом более маленькие

Comment: Нет, не пробовал, надо попробовать

Comment: Если сначала поставить большие, потом маленькие то все, вроде бы выставляется на поле. Но у меня осталась проблема с методом isCanSetShip() класса Field. Не могу довести до умного вида. Иногда между кораблями нет свободной ячейки.

Comment: А кто сказал, что установка рядом - это плохо, с одной стороны конечно могут случайно наткнутся при поиске "палуб", с другой, может после подбитого корабля рядом искать не будут :)

Comment: По правилам же нельзя :) Я бы для небольших полей завел матрицу `boolean` с запасом по клетке в обе стороны (от -1 до FIELDSIZE+1), чтобы не делать особые случаи для краев, и при установке корабля устанавливал соответствующие клетки, и все клетки рядом в `true`. Перед установкой можно проверить все клетки под новым кораблем, если они `false` - корабль можно ставить.

Comment: @zRrr, не совсем понял ход ваших мыслей. Вы советуете вместо char использовать boolean размером 12 на 12? Или как?

Comment: Или просто заведите список уже выставленных на поле кораблей (координаты начала, ориентация и размер), определите для класса `Ship` метод, проверяющий попадание точки в область вокруг корабля, и убеждайтесь, что ни одна из точек нового корабля не попадает в эти области уже добавленных кораблей

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запретная зона вокруг корабля представляет собой прямоугольник, внутри которого не должно быть других кораблей. Зная верхнюю левую и нижнюю правую точки, можно проверить все точки внутри. Чтобы не возиться с частными случаями, можно просто обрезать проверяемую область.

```
public boolean canSetShip( Ship ship ) {
    // проверяем, что наш корабль попадает в поле
    if ( ship.positionX < 0 || ship.positionY < 0 || FIELDSIZE <= ship.positionX || FIELDSIZE <= ship.positionY ) return false;
    if ( ship.isVertical && FIELDSIZE <= ship.positionY + ship.size ) return false;
    if ( !ship.isVertical && FIELDSIZE <= ship.positionX + ship.size ) return false;

    // проверяем, что в зоне вокруг корабля никого нет
    // обрезаем зону
    int minX = Math.max( 0, ship.positionX - 1 );
    int minY = Math.max( 0, ship.positionY - 1 );
    int maxX = Math.min( FIELDSIZE - 1, ship.positionX + 1 + (ship.isVertical ? 0 : ship.size) );
    int maxY = Math.min( FIELDSIZE - 1, ship.positionY + 1 + (ship.isVertical ? ship.size : 0) );

    // сама проверка
    for ( int x = minX; x <= maxX; x++ ) {
        for ( int y = minY; y <= maxY; y++ ) {
            if ( isShipPresent( x, y ) ) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Еще вам стоит переделать установку кораблей (странно, что "вертикальный" корабль расположен по оси X) и вывод поля (сейчас у вас `cells[positionX][positionY]` при `positionX = 5; positionY = 3` выведется, как 4ая ячейка в 6ой строке).

Comment: Спасибо что указали на ошибку:) Переименовал переменную, которая отвечает за положение корабля, а в методе переписать код просто забыл и получился такой каламбур:)  Ваш метод работает, корабли не "слипаются". А я просто что-то напутал в проверке. Ну а на счет вывода поля - что-то я не могу найти проблемы.

Answer (score 4):

По самому алгоритму.
Большие корабли (3 и 4 - палубные - в любом случае) надо расставлять по стенкам, чтобы их запретная зона не мешала другим кораблям прятаться, и проблема размещения снимается.
Да, на стенке проще искать. Зато потом замучаются однопалубные по всей карте искать. Так что алгоритм ещё и усилится.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/52122)

Comment: Но тогда алгоритм становится более предсказуемым — можно простреливать стенки в поисках больших кораблей, и если есть попадание, то исключается вариант, когда корабль стоит носом/кормой к краю поля. )

Comment: Это не беда что все длинные корабли потопят сразу. Площадь для поиска оставшихся однопалубных кораблей будет больше, чем если бы длинные были раскиданы внутри. Тут поможет только везение.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin На стороне такого решения - теория вероятности и игровой опыт.

Comment: @cyadvert Алгоритм  расставляет корабли рандомно и в итоге не может разместить их все. При растановке больших кораблей по стенкам проблема снимается. И есть баунти - усиление  алгоритма. Так ответ это или нет?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov при случайной расстановке без подобных трюков алгоритм вполне справляется если начинать с больших, а не с маленьких :-)