# Консольный морской бой на java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, пишу примитивную версию морского боя на java. Знаю, тема такая была, но из рассмотренных мною вариантов логику работы так и не понял, поэтому решил писать свой вариант. На данный момент не пойму как в двумерном массиве разместить корабли чтобы они не соприкасались и не перекрывали друг друга. Вот сами классы программы:

```
public class Runner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Game game = new Game();
     game.startGame();
  }
}


public class Game {
  public void startGame() {
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    cell.fillField();
    cell.viewField();
    cell.autoInitField();//в данном методе не соображу как размещать корабли
    cell.viewField();
  }
}


public class Cell {
   static final int SIZE = 10; // фиксированный размер поля для игры
   char cells[][] = new char[SIZE][SIZE]; // создание поля
   FactoryShip factoryShip = new FactoryShip();
   Ship arrShipOfCell[]; //Данному массиву присвоится массив кораблей 
                         //созданных в классе FactoryShip

public void fillField() {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            cells[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public void viewField() {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            System.out.print(cells[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

 void autoInitField() {
    arrShipOfCell = factoryShip.initShip();
    //Не знаю как поместить корабли в cells[][]
 }
}


import java.util.Random;

 public class FactoryShip {
  static final int DECK[] = {1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4}; // колличество палуб у 
                                                   // кораблей
  Random random = new Random();
  Ship ship;
  Ship arrShips[] = new Ship[10];

  Ship[] initShip(){
     for (int i = 0; i < DECK.length; i++) {
        int tmp = random.nextInt((Cell.SIZE + 1) - DECK[i]);//начальные 
                                         //координаты размещения корабля
        ship = new Ship(DECK[i],tmp,(tmp + i));
        arrShips[i] = ship;
    }
    return arrShips;
  }
}


public class Ship {
 private int deck, xPosition, yPosition;

 Ship(int deck, int x, int y) {
    this.deck = deck;
    this.xPosition = x;
    this.yPosition = y;
 }

 public int getDeck() {
    return deck;
 }
 public int getxPosition() {
    return xPosition;
 }
 public int getyPosition() {
    return yPosition;
 }
}
```

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации, добавьте описание конкретных проблем, с которыми вы столкнулись.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Морской бой. Как правильно расставить корабли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478636/%d0%9c%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Comment: Спасибо за конструктивную критику, буду следить чтобы больше не повторилось.

Comment: Вообщем я все классы переделал. Но при добавлении на игровое поле 2-ух кораблей периодически вылетает исключение **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**. [Ссылка на ошибку](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3KIIbzlo9Plc1lHQlVPYVo4cmc), а при добавлении 3-ёх кораблей исключение выпадает постоянно. Так понимаю в классе **Cell**, в методе 'coincideShip(Ship ship)', при проверке ячеек на занятость происходит выход за пределы массива, подскажите пожалуйста, что можно предпринять для решения проблемы [ссылка на исходники](https://github.com/goodwin039/newSeaBattle/tree/master/src).

Answer (score 1):

Можно, допустим, создать многомерный массив(например, если у тебя 16 клеток, то 4 подмассива(1 линия на поле) по 4 элемента(1 клетка на линии)), и пустая клетка 0, а заполненная клетка - 1(2,3,4). Конечно это все очень примитивно.

Например: `int userField [16] = {{},{},{},{}}`
Можно сделать проверку, что-бы рядом с числом больше 0 добавлялся в массив только 0. Ну все, я и так уже много написал, т.к. твой вопрос вообще не соответствует [правилам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4882/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0).

Comment: Вообщем я все классы переделал. Но при добавлении на игровое поле 2-ух кораблей периодически вылетает исключение **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**. [Ссылка на ошибку](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3KIIbzlo9Plc1lHQlVPYVo4cmc), а при добавлении 3-ёх кораблей исключение выпадает постоянно. Так понимаю в классе **Cell**, в методе 'coincideShip(Ship ship)', при проверке ячеек на занятость происходит выход за пределы массива, подскажите пожалуйста, что можно предпринять для решения проблемы [ссылка на исходники](https://github.com/goodwin039/newSeaBattle/tree/master/src).

Comment: @student007 ну можно добавить еще "окаймление" - например, с цифрой 3(тогда будет 5на5).

Comment: Уточню по-поводу окаймления - требуется в методе `'coincideShip(Ship ship)` в месте приращения переменной **dx** и **dy** увеличить диапазон до 3 или вы что-то другое имели ввиду? Если увеличить до 3-ёх то пробовал, исключение всё равно вылетает.